# How can I install httpd 2.2 in /etc/ directory in CentoOS 7

Tags: apache-2.2, installation, httpd, centos7

CentOS 7 has got only httpd 2.4 available in its repositories. I downloaded the 2.2 version and I did a manual installation, but httpd was installed in /usr/local/ directory.

Is there any way to do the manual installation with /etc/ directory as target?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reasoning for requiring an older version of httpd, please?

Comment: `/etc/` is the location for config files, not for binaries. Apache has no place there. Or do you want to place just the config files in `/etc`? And yes, why Apache 2.2? If you need the older version, you could stick with CentOS 6.

Comment: I'm migrating from Ubuntu to CentOS and I want to keep the same version of Apache server

Comment: Basically, you don't need and should not need the 2.2 on fresh installation. 2.4 is fully compatible with 2.2 configurations.

Comment: @drookie: No, it is not. There are some minor but important differences, e.g. in the auth control area, and you have to adapt your config if you use these. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: This is like 10 minutes of work.

Comment: @drookie: I didn't say it was complicated, just that you *have* to adapt it and they are not fully compatible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the option `--prefix=/etc/httpd` with `./configure` while installing.

`./configure --prefix=/etc/httpd --your-other-options...`

Comment: As I said, Apache binaries doesn't belong into `/etc`.

Comment: @Sven , I think the OP wants all the config files in /etc/ directory just like a regular rpm installation. In that case, the `--prefix` options works and is recommended.

Comment: I honestly never tried it, but reading http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/configure.html confirms this.

Comment: That works Sree. Thank you. Anyway I'll try test with official 2.4 version too.